# Trouble with std::map ('map' is not a member of 'std')

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I am trying to use the std::map but it fails every time I try to build. I have included these strange errors I am getting and hopefully you can tell where I went wrong. Using the visual studio default header.

Code:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::map < int, int > x = {};
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// TODO: add headers that you want to pre-compile here

#endif //PCH_H
```

[image: Errors]

Comment: You say "no header", yet you have a highly suspicious `pch.h` in there.

Comment: Isn't that silly Windows pch.h header supposed to be *first* one included to be able to work right?

Comment: Updated! Sorry about that.

Comment: In Visual Studio the default is to use precompiled headers. If it's enabled the inclusion of `"pch.h"` needs to be the very first non-comment (or non-empty) line in the source file.

Comment: @Shawn Yep.  OP: pch.h needs to be the first header.  Everything before it is ignored if it isn't.

Comment: Oh yikes, it works with pch.h header on top! What a surprise lol.